# Should I delete or flag to close my own question that is a duplicate?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, post-ban

I asked this question https://superuser.com/q/674809/241659 and after that, I found a similar question [Firefox 4 default address bar behaviour](https://superuser.com/q/279459/241659) that answers my question.

I am a little less on upvotes for my questions and I get frequently blocked out from asking questions on Super User. I don't want that to happen again. So, what is better to do?
Should I delete my question or should I just vote it to close?

Comment: Short answer: vote to close

Comment: I believe 1000 reputation is the cutoff for any automatic blocks, so that shouldn't happen to you again (unless suspended by a moderator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's preferable to vote to close your question as duplicate; if someone else searches with the same keywords that you've used, it'll redirect them to the dupe question